# Jquery Show/Hide Click Function Not Working

Tags: jquery, asp.net

In my page I have `textboxes` and `buttons`.

For `textbox1` I wrote a `click` function to `toggle`. When I click `textbox1`, the toogle function works; it displays `#something` and I can select `#something`. But if I click a `button` on same page for `#something` then click `textbox1` again, the `toogle` function does not work. Below is my code. Any ideas?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#textbox1").click(function () {
        $('#Something').toggle("1000"); 
    });
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Edit:

Here is the html:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td> 
      <asp:TextBox ID="textbox1" placeholder=" -- select --" Width="200px" Height ="35px" runat="server" CssClass="search"></asp:TextBox>
      <asp:Button ID="btn1" Width="20px" Height ="35px" runat="server" Text="V" OnClick="btn1_Click" /> 
    </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Please provide the `HTML`

Comment: <table ><tr><td>
      
 <asp:TextBox ID="textbox1" placeholder=" -- select --"  Width="200px" Height ="35px" runat="server" CssClass="search"></asp:TextBox>
                                 
<asp:Button ID="btn1" Width="20px" Height ="35px" runat="server" Text="V"  OnClick="btn1_Click" />
 </td></tr></table>

Comment: What is `onclick="btn1_click"` doing? Perhaps this is conflicting with the `toggle` function?

Comment: Dude, edit your question and include your HTML. Not the ASPX stuff. But the actual HTML that gets output to the page. And make sure to include your '#something' which doesn't exist in the HTML you put in your question.

Comment: @camelCase - that's the Asp.Net click event handler. He didn't post the actual HTML. He posted his Asp.Net server side page. It won't conflict with the toggle function but It will cause a post back to the server when the button is clicked.

Comment: I thought that looked odd ;) I know nothing of asp.net, figured it was a JavaScript function or something, thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 0):

an asp textbox with `runat="server"` will NOT have the same id when built

you'd have to use `$("#<%= Textbox1.ClientID %>").click()`

Answer (score 0):

The `asp:Textbox` will create an html `<input />` tag. The id of the html tag may be different than the id of the `asp:Textbox` server control.

There are two ways to resolve this question:

1. Change your javascript to inject the following:

   `$("#<%= Textbox1.ClientID %>").click()`

Note, this will not work if your javascript is in an external file.

2. Force .NET to make the id of the `<input />` tag the same as your server control. You can do this by adding the following property to your server tag: `ClientIdMode="static"`. Like so:

   `<asp:TextBox ID="textbox1" ClientIdMode="static" ...>`